# Django migrate to MySql

Tags: python, mysql, django, migrate

In my Django app, I have this in the settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<myname>',
        'USER': '<myuser>',
        'PASSWORD': '<mypassowrd>',
        'HOST': 'db677888126.db.1and1.com',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

I get this when running `python manage.py inspectdb` in the shell:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'db677888126.db.1and1.com' (0)")
```

However the connection works in PHP with the same variables... Why?

Comment: did you install the MySQL drivers https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the Django project from the same machine as you ran your PHP code from? The hostname you've posted does not resolve from my DNS server. I imagine it is only resolvable inside 1and1's network.

Comment: No it is a different machine, but I don't see why the host name should change another machine?

Comment: Your provider has only made your database server available from the machine your site runs on. It is very common to not allow direct internet access to database servers. Are you trying to access it from your local development environment?

Comment: Okay so I guess, I have to talk to 1 & 1 then. Thanks for your time!

Comment: No worries. To help other users who come across the same issue, please consider accepting this answer by using the check mark above. Cheers.